# Check if variable is false and not either true or undefined

Tags: javascript, variables, if-statement, undefined

What's the best way to check if `myvar` javascript `variable === false` or not (it may be undefined as well).

```
if (myvar === false)
```

would be fine but `myvar` could be undefined. Only `false` value is acceptable, not undefined.

Any shorter than `if (typeof myvar !== "undefined" && myvar === false)`?

Comment: *Only* `false` or `undefined`, or are you simply looking for any "falsy" value, which would be just `if (myvar) ...` ?

Comment: what you should should work fine, or if you REALLY wanted to be explicit then `if((myvar === false) && (myvar !== undefined)){`

Answer (score 67, accepted):

If the variable is *declared* then:

```
if (myvar === false) {
```

will work fine. `===` won't consider `false` to be undefined.

If it is `undefined` *and* undeclared then you should check its type before trying to use it (otherwise you will get a reference error).

```
if(typeof myvar === 'boolean' && myvar === false) {
```

That said, you should ensure that the variable is always declared if you plan to try to use it.

```
var myvar;
// ...
// some code that may or may not assign a value to myvar
// ...
if (myvar === false) {
```

Answer (score 8):

```
if(typeof myvar === 'boolean' && !myvar)
```

Answer (score 4):

How about `if (myvar !== undefined && myvar === false)` ?

Comment: `undefined` can be redefined to some other values, so you should always use `typeof` or defined a local `undefined`.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 Not in modern browsers anymore.

Comment: @IngoBürk - Most users on the internet do not have modern browsers, especially computers in commercial environments.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 You can easily look up statistics to see that most users on the internet *do* in fact use a browser which is modern enough to disallow this. Either way, however, if you have code that redefined `undefined`, you are doing something very, very wrong anyway. If a library does it, get rid of the library.

Comment: (I personally still prefer the `typeof` check for semantic reasons, I'm just arguing the point about redefining the value)

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 it still holds for edge as of 3rd January 2024

Answer (score 0):

In nodejs by using [node-boolify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-boolify) it is possible

```
var Boolify = require('node-boolify').Boolify;
if (Boolify(myVar) == false) {
    //Instructions when satisfy
} else {
    //Instructions when not satisfy
}
```

**Boolean Conversion Results**

```
Boolify(true); //true
Boolify('true'); //true
Boolify('TRUE'); //null
Boolify(1); //true
Boolify(2); //null
Boolify(false); //false
Boolify('false'); //false
Boolify('FALSE'); //null
Boolify(0); //false
Boolify(null); //null
Boolify(undefined); //null
Boolify(); //null
Boolify(''); //null
```

Answer (score 0):

Using lodash you can use [isBoolean](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#isBoolean) func

```
if(isBoolean(myvar) && myvar === false)
```